# If $f$ is a bijection, then $g$ is also a bijection.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets, and $f: A$ to $B$ and $g: B$ to $A$ two functions. Is the following statement True or False?

If $f$ is a bijection, then $g$ is a bijection.

Answer : False.

I don't understand why this is False, I got the other multiple choice right on my practice exam, but can't seem to grasp this one. Does anybody have an example of either what set $A$ and or $B$ could look like for this to be False? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there some connection between $f,g$?

Comment: $g$ has absolutely nothing to do with $f$?

Comment: @lulu That's all the info. we just know that f and g are two functions. I guess it could be anything, and maybe that's why I'm confused...

Comment: That seems really unlikely.  But, obviously, if $f,g$ have no connection then information about $f$ tells us nothing about $g$.

Comment: If they're completely unrelated, then any information about $f$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @lulu that makes sense, I guess I just didn't catch that, I just looked over the exam and all the other multiple choices gave additional info on how f and g were related. I guess I just assumed they were related since they were both using set A and set B.

Comment: Just because one function between $A $ and $B $ is bijective, does not mean all functions between  $A $ and $B $ are bijective.

Comment: I think they're trying to confuse you with simplicity :-) If the two functions are totally unrelated and you know nothing about $A$ and $B$ then one could be a bijection and the other not. It's so simple they are trying to get you to overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

As there is such little connection between $f$ and $g$ there's no reason to think that they must share a lot of properties. Basically $f$ is a red heering here. The question is if a function $B\to A$ has to be bijective and no it hasn't (even if $A$ and $B$ has the same number of elements and more than one element).

Let for example $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$ and define $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=1$ then obviously $f$ is bijective, but $g$ is not (because $g(1)=g(2)=1$.